# Problemas al guardar datos con LARAVEL 5.5

Tags: laravel

Tengo 2 metodos uno para guardar y otro para consultar y los tengo de la siguiente manera:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{

    $comment = new Comment();
    $comment->user_id = $request->user_id;
    $comment->factura_id = $request->factura_id;
    $comment->comment = $request->comment;
    $comment->save();

    if ( $request->ajax() ){
        return $comment;
    }

}

public function show($id)
{
    $comments = Comment::select('*')->where('factura_id', $id)->with('user:id,name')->get();

    return $comments;
}
```

Todo funcionaba bien pero hoy 13-01-2017 al querer guardar me da un error me dice:

> SQLSTATE[22007]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]La conversión del tipo de datos nvarchar en datetime produjo un
>   valor fuera de intervalo. (SQL: insert into [comments] ([user_id],
>   [factura_id], [comment], [updated_at], [created_at]) values (1, 554,
>   commeny, 2018-01-13 14:25:44.015, 2018-01-13 14:25:44.015))

No me deja guardar por los metodos de created_at y updated_at, la solucion facil es quitarlos pero no quiero porque los necesito, y no se de que manera solucionarlo. intente hacerlo agregando un mi modelo

```
protected $dateFormat = 'Ymd h:i:s';
```

y me funciona, puedo guardar pero al hacer la consulta me dice:

```
Unexpected data found. Unexpected data found. Trailing data
```

Alguna solucion colegas???

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que estas insertando una fecha que contiene milisegundos, en el formato **datetime** de sql que es `"Y-m-d H:m:s"`,

la solución mas rápida es insertar manualmente los timestamps en el formato correcto

```
$comment->created_at = date('Y-m-d H:m:s');

$comment->updated_at = date('Y-m-d H:m:s');

$comment->save();
```

Comment: Eso lo solucina pero si quiero que se siga agregado solo el created_at y el updated_at solo sabes de alguna solución?

Answer (score 2):

Te recomiendo que hagas otra clase y que todos tus modelos hagan `extends` de esa nueva clase. 
Lo ideal es que sobreescribas la función dateFormat de Model.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class BaseModel extends Model 
{

    public function getDateFormat()
    {
        $database = env('DB_CONNECTION');

        $date_format = parent::getDateFormat();
        if ($database == 'sqlsrv') 
            $date_format = 'Ymd H:i:s';

        return $date_format;
    }
}

class User extends BaseModel
{
    //
}
```

Entonces si utilizas SQL debe usar el formato Ymd H:i:s.

Answer (score 0):

Por que no añades esto a tu migracion donde se esta creando la tabla comments?

```
$table->timestamps();
```

Eso te va a crear automaticamente el update_at y el created_at, sin formateos ni complicaciones.
Te pongo un ejemplo:

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Y una captura de mi DB:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando crees un comment, directamente se creara la fecha y hora en el created_at y el updated_at.